# Docker Standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused “no such file or directory”

Tags: docker, dockerfile, entry-point, docker-entrypoint

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get ...
...
COPY app /bin
```

And my executable `app` is just bash script:

```
make -f /app/makefile $@
```

When I try to run

```
docker run -v "`pwd`:/project" -it --rm my_image app
```

I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you entrypoint is bash script check whether it contains correct shebang, something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
make -f /app/makefile $@
```

Either specify it in your entrypoint command, something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/bin/app"]
```